# .getSelectedItem() is not working in combo box

Tags: java, methods, swt, getselection

```
Combo comboLevels = new Combo(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
    comboLevels.setBounds(52, 31, 91, 23);
    String[] items = new String[] { "Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swdish 3" 
};
        comboLevels.setItems(items);
//this is in main
//as a method i need to getselected item for example id "swedish1 " is clicked i need to store it somewhere and then get a class that does what "swedish1" needs to do
//as a method i have,nothing more yet it still gives me red highlights:

static int counter = 1;
static String level;
static String value;`

void Question() {
        level = comboLevels.getSelectedItem(); 
}
```

My code includes these lines of code. Yet eclipse is telling me and underlining `comboLevels.getSelectedItem()` in red and stating that it is "undefined" for the type combo box. Eclipse is also suggesting me to change it to `comboLevels.getSelection()`. and when I run it as selection there seems to be some kind of error when the part of the code is executed.

If someone could help this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post more code of your class ?

Comment: my class is quite big so it wont let me post it here

Comment: static int counter = 1;
 static String level;
 static String value;

 void Question() {
  level = comboLevels.getSelectedItem();

Comment: Combo comboLevels = new Combo(shellAfterCasual, SWT.NONE);
  comboLevels.setBounds(52, 31, 91, 23);
  String[] items = new String[] { "Swedish 1", "Swedish 2", "Swdish 3" };
  comboLevels.setItems(items);

Comment: take a look now